# Database for Unity Android Application

Tags: c#, database, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am working on an android application in Unity. I am new in it and now I am at the stage when I have to create and connect a database to my project (I have to store information about users and their interaction with some options in app). Can you help me to choose database, which will be a best fit for me? Are there some tutorials related to connection with unity ?

I have to mention that I want it to be NoSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use fauna db or firebase both are pretty much free. For unity I'd use firebase because they have documentation on how to use it in unity.